# C# Asp.net Webforms simple SQL Query for 1 row several columns to variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, webforms

I have been searching around and I am either confusing myself or not searching for the right thing.

I have this data reader that pulls some information for a store procedure.. but I don't think I am doing it right.

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PAYROLL"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DLI_EMPLOYEE_PORTAL_EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID", Session["sessionEMPID"].ToString());
        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            string EMP_FIRST = dataReader["FIRST_NAME"].ToString();
            string EMP_LAST = dataReader["LAST_NAME"].ToString();
            string EMP_DEPT = dataReader["DEPT"].ToString();
            string EMP_DEPT_ID = dataReader["DEPT_ID"].ToString();

            body = body + "<p>SUBMITTED BY : (" + Session["sessionEMPID"].ToString() + ") " + EMP_FIRST + " " + EMP_LAST + " - DEPT : " + EMP_DEPT + "</p> " + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I just need to query one row based of an employee ID.. and I would rather do it not by stored procedure but a select query.

```
SELECT e.FIRST_NAME, e.LAST_NAME, e.DEPT_ID, d.NAME 
FROM EMPLOYEE AS e 
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT AS d ON e.DEPT_ID = d.ID 
WHERE (e.ID = 'sim01')
```

I am building an HTML body string so that is why I need the information.

```
body = body + "<p>SUBMITTED BY : (" + Session["sessionEMPID"].ToString() + ") " + EMP_FIRST + " " + EMP_LAST + " - DEPT : " + EMP_DEPT + "</p> " + System.Environment.NewLine;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Your code looks pretty good, but you should read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: So you want to use a select statement instead of a stored procedure. Great. What's preventing you from doing that? Have you tried it? What went wrong with your implementation?

Comment: Isn't the data reader looping?  I guess I am looking for my like classic ASP.

Comment: strSQLQuery = "...."
Set MyRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

Set MyRS = dli.Execute(strSQLQuery)

'RESPONSE.WRITE "<p><p>last name:" & (MyRS("LAST_NAME"))

Comment: Well you have a while loop, so technically you have a loop. If only one row is returned then it's going to go through the loop once. I suggest you look into [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), it has a far better syntax for working with ADO.NET. It would allow you to do something like `var information = con.Query("your select command", new { EmployeeId = Session["sessionEMPID"].ToString()} ).SingleOrDefault());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is use a query instead of a stored procedure, just pass your SQL statement to the Command and set your CommandType to Text.  If you only ever expect one row, use `if (dataReader.Read()` instead of `while (dataReader.Read())`.

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PAYROLL"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT e.FIRST_NAME, e.LAST_NAME, e.DEPT_ID, d.NAME " + 
        "FROM EMPLOYEE AS e " +
        "INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT AS d ON e.DEPT_ID = d.ID " + 
        "WHERE (e.ID = @EID)"));
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID", Session["sessionEMPID"].ToString());
        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        if (dataReader.Read())
        {
            string EMP_FIRST = dataReader["FIRST_NAME"].ToString();
            string EMP_LAST = dataReader["LAST_NAME"].ToString();
            string EMP_DEPT = dataReader["DEPT"].ToString();
            string EMP_DEPT_ID = dataReader["DEPT_ID"].ToString();

            body = body + "<p>SUBMITTED BY : (" + Session["sessionEMPID"].ToString() + ") " + EMP_FIRST + " " + EMP_LAST + " - DEPT : " + EMP_DEPT + "</p> " + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

If the query can return more than one row, you can add `TOP 1` to the query with an `ORDER BY <some other field>` to grab only the most relevant one.

Answer (score 0):

It us better to use query instead of stored procedure if there is no TSQL logic